# Как реализовать такой текст (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

Доброго утра, как реализовать такой текст с горизонтальными полосами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент разметка такая:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

.form_section2 {
 width: 100%;
}

div.map {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Releway;
    font-size: 18px;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 40px 0 60.5px 0;
}

.map{
 min-height: 281px;
 width: auto;
}

.content_two{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: -15px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
.content_two p{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 00px  0 00px;
 width: auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #F8FCFD;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
 <div class="form_section2">

 <div class="content_two">КАРТА КЛИЕНТОВ</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Af60a70598626f9f1c522be935b35f06356d8ac548df2d1c16e0464adaf3d764b&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать:

```css
.line-behind {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line-behind:before {
  right: 6.5%;
}

.line-behind:after {
    left: 6.5%;
}

.line-behind:before,
.line-behind:after {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.title:before {
  border-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-behind">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а проверить сложно?

Comment: вы это кому? :)

Comment: @Flippy тому, кто про IE спрашивал